# I want data in a single row according to schcd,entry_date and mobile_no

Tags: mysql

[image: table structure and sample data]

I have written the following query

```
SELECT distcd,blkcd,schcd,entry_date,mobile_no,
class1,class2,class3,class4,class5,class6,class7,class8,class9,class10,
class11,class12 
FROM adhoc_studentatt_details_prv 
WHERE SCHCD='20130100101' AND entry_date='2019-05-01 00:00:00' and mobile_no='9801355122'
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`, to get your desired output.

It will group the columns by the `distcd, blkcd, schcd, entry_date, mobile_no` and return the result in one row.

```
SELECT distcd,
    blkcd,
    schcd,
    entry_date,
    mobile_no,
    MAX(class1) AS class1,
    MAX(class2) AS class2,
    MAX(class3) AS class3,
    MAX(class4) AS class4,
    MAX(class5) AS class5,
    MAX(class6) AS class6,
    MAX(class7) AS class7,
    MAX(class8) AS class8,
    MAX(class9) AS class9,
    MAX(class10) AS class10,
    MAX(class11) AS class11,
    MAX(class12) AS class12
FROM adhoc_studentatt_details_prv
WHERE SCHCD = '20130100101'
    AND entry_date = '2019-05-01 00:00:00'
    AND mobile_no = '9801355122'
GROUP BY distcd, blkcd, schcd, entry_date, mobile_no
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to group and concatenate the corresponding values to return a single row result.

[GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) can do the trick.